# Windows 7 like calender widget for android

Tags: android, widget

I would like to install calender widget in my android device (`lollipop`)

I need a widget that looks like native calender widget in `Windows 7`

[image]

I've searched a lot but didn't  get one :( , Is there any app is available(free/paid)

Comment: What features does that widget need to have – except for "looking like that"? Pointer, while waiting for replies: [there's a listing of calendar widgets](http://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/office_calendar_widgets) on my Android site ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Month: Calendar Widget](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.candl.chronos&hl=en)

It really suits in your device because a material design widget is available in that in addition to that you can set events and this will notify in the widget

NOTE :  It's not looks same as windows 7's widget but it will looks much better in lollipop device because of it's material design

[image]

[image]